# Laravel 4 re-factoring contact form from controller to model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, swiftmailer

Before I started re-factoring this code, it worked. After moving all the business logic to the model and adding a try/catch block to the controller, everything seems correct. When I fill out the form and hit send, I get a success message, but don't receive the email. Where am I going wrong?

**Controller**

```
class ContactController extends BaseController {

    protected $contact;

    public function __construct(Contact $contact)
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'post'));
        $this->contact = $contact;
    }

    public function serve()
    {
        return View::make('layouts.contact');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->contact->sendMessage(Input::all());
        }

       catch (ValidationError $e)
       {
           return Redirect::back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($e->getErrors());
       }

    return Redirect::to('contact')
            ->with('message', 'Your message was successfully sent!');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Contact extends Eloquent {

    public function sendMessage($input)
    {
        $validation = new Services\Validators\Contact;

        if($validation->passes())
        {
            $fromEmail = Input::get('email');
            $fromName = Input::get('name');
            $subject = "Email from user";
            $data = [ 'msg' => Input::get('message') ];

            $toEmail = 'logistics@praestavi.com';
            $toName = 'Mitch Glenn';

            Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject){

                $message->to($toEmail, $toName);

                $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);

                $message->subject($subject);
            });
        }

        else
        {
            $this->errors = $validation->errors;
            throw new ValidationError($validation->errors);
        }
    }
}
```

To re-summarize the problem: The form works, but after submitting and receiving success message, I don't get the email. Thanks for taking time to look over my code.

Edit: Adding requested Validator

**Contact.php**

```
<?php namespace Services\Validators;

class Contact extends Validator {

    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

**Validator.php**

```
<?php namespace Services\Validators;

abstract class Validator {

    protected $attributes;
    public $errors;

    public function __construct($attributes = null)
    {
    $this->attributes = $attributes ?: \Input::all();
    }

    public function passes()
    {
        $validation = \Validator::make($this->attributes, static::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes()) return true;

        $this->errors = $validation->messages();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's like they say: live and learn!

Comment: Hmm, maybe something wrong with your "Mail" module?

Comment: @neoascetic I'm not sure what would be wrong with it though since it worked before I moved it into the model from the controller.

Comment: Please show your Contact validator

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've literally just refactored your code here, I would start adding some debugging around the `Mail::send()` call. Maybe wrap it inside a `dd()` function. You should see an integer; the number of recipients the message was successfully sent to.

Also, what's your `app/config/mail.php` contents look like (please remove any sensitive passwords).